# Time difference in hours

Tags: ruby, time

I am trying to get the difference in hours for two different Time instances. I get these values from the DB as a `:datetime` column

How can I do this so that it includes the months and years as well in the calculation while ignoring or rounding the minutes? Can this only be done manually or is there a function to do this?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

```
((date_2 - date_1) / 3600).round
```

or

```
((date_2 - date_1) / 1.hour).round
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. Perhaps it has changed since 2009? Now, I have to do `(date_2 - date_1) * 24` to get the hours

Comment: Works totally fine for me on Rails 4.2.

Comment: @Jeff, sorry i dont understand english very well. Are you being sarcastic and is the answer wrong?

Comment: Second answer does not work on Ruby 2.4.x. Consider using first option

Comment: Both options do work with Ruby 2.4.x and Rails 4 or 5, as long as the objects are instances of `Time` or `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` (what you usually get from a `datetime` database column). On the other hand with instances of `Date` or `Datetime` you'd need to multiply by 24 to achieve the same effect, since the internal unit is the day, and not the second.

Comment: To convert to a ActiveSupport object 
```((date_2 - date_1) / 1.hour).round => #Float``` 
```((date_2 - date_1) / 1.hour).round.seconds => #ActiveSupport::Duration```

Answer (score 19):

Try Time Difference gem for Ruby at https://rubygems.org/gems/time_difference

```
start_time = Time.new(2013,1)
end_time = Time.new(2014,1)
TimeDifference.between(start_time, end_time).in_years
```

Comment: how to call duration only with hours? with out passing the date and year and month

Comment: @HarshaMV You mean like: `44.hours - 2.hours # => 42.hours`?

Answer (score 12):

this works great, example for number of hours since user created account

```
(Time.parse(DateTime.now.to_s) - Time.parse(current_user.created_at.to_s))/3600
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a gem called [time_diff](https://rubygems.org/gems/time_diff) to get the time difference in very useful formats

Answer (score 6):

### in_hours (Rails 6.1+)

Rails 6.1 introduces new [ActiveSupport::Duration](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html) conversion methods like [in_seconds](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_seconds), [in_minutes](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_minutes), [in_hours](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_hours), [in_days](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_days), [in_weeks](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_weeks), [in_months](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_months), and [in_years](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_years).

As a result, now, your problem can be solved as:

```rb
date_1 = Time.parse('2020-10-19 00:00:00 UTC')
date_2 = Time.parse('2020-10-19 03:35:38 UTC') 

(date_2 - date_1).seconds.in_hours.to_i
# => 3
```

Here is [a link to the corresponding PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/38699).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Rails' method `distance_of_time_in_words`

```
distance_of_time_in_words(starting_time, ending_time, options = {include_seconds: true })
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this is approximate. For example `distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(DateTime.now - 36.hours)` will return `1 day`

Answer (score 4):

In Rails, there is now a **far more natural way** to achieve this:

```
> past = Time.now.beginning_of_year
2018-01-01 00:00:00 +0100

> (Time.now - past) / 1.day
219.50031326506948
```