# Calculating difference in time between two Time objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

Let's say I create two time objects from my user model:

```
created = u.created_at
updated = u.updated_at
```

How do I calculate the difference in terms of hours between the two time objects?

```
hours = created - updated
```

I'd like to wrap this in a method and extend the Time class.  I find it hard to believe I'd need to extend it, but I can't seem to find a native method that handles calculating elapsed time using different time units.

Comment: Take a look at the TimeDifference gem: https://github.com/tmlee/time_difference

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This should work:

```
hours = ((created - updated) / 1.hour).round
```

Related question: [Rails Time difference in hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736253/rails-time-difference-in-hours)

Answer (score 14):

Another option would be to use distance_of_time_in_words helper:

```
<%= distance_of_time_in_words u.created_at, u.updated_at %>
```

I hope you find it useful :)

Comment: If you need to use this where `distance_of_time_in_words` is not pre-loaded, like the console, you can use this to import it: `include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper`.

Comment: Also check out https://github.com/doorkeeper/dotiw if you need more precise words, like "1 year, 2 months, 4 hours, 5 minutes, and 6 seconds".

Answer (score 11):

I would like to add an alternate answer using a rails-specific method. The Time class has a method called minus_with_coercion. It compares two times and returns a result in seconds.

```
hours=(created.minus_with_coercion(updated)/3600).round
```

Comment: A little late I know :) But the created and updated. What format are they in? Seconds?