# Ruby iterate over hours

Tags: ruby, loops, time

Let's say I have some user input with start and end hours:

- start = 09:00
- end = 01:00

How do I display all the hours between those 2? So from 09 to 23, 0, and then to 1.

There are easy cases:

- start = 01:00
- end = 04:00

That's just a matter of
`((start_hour.to_i)..(end_hour.to_i))`.select { |hour| }

Comment: I'm presuming here that the span in time is always 23 hours or less, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved with a custom Enumerator implementation:

```
def hours(from, to)
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    while (from != to)
      y << from
      from += 1
      from %= 24
    end
    y << from
  end
end
```

That gives you something you can use like this:

```
hours(9, 1).each do |hour|
  puts hour
end
```

Or if you want an Array:

```
hours(9,1).to_a
#=> [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a oneliner `(0..23).to_a.rotate(start_h)[0...end_h - start_h]`

```
def hours_between(start_h, end_h)
    (0..23).to_a.rotate(start_h)[0...end_h - start_h]
end

hours_between(1, 4)
# [1, 2, 3]
hours_between(4, 4)
# []
hours_between(23, 8)
# [23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Don't forget to sanitize the input (That they are number between 0 and 23) :)

If you want the finishing hour use `..` instead of `...` => `[0..end_h - start_h]`

If you care about performance or want something evaluated lazily you can also do the following (reading the code is really clear):

```
(0..23).lazy.map {|h| (h + start_h) % 24 }.take_while { |h| h != end_h }
```

Answer (score 0):

With a simple condition:

```
def hours(from, to)
  if from <= to
    (from..to).to_a
  else
    (from..23).to_a + (0..to).to_a
  end
end

hours(1, 9)
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

hours(9, 1)
#=> [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1]
```

You could also use the shorter, but more cryptic `[*from..23, *0..to]` notation.

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6784628/3012550 shows how to iterate over the number of hours in the distance between two times.

I would use that, and at each iteration use `start + i.hours`

```
def hours(number)
  number * 60 * 60
end

((end_time - start_time) / hours(1)).round.times do |i|
  print start_time + hours(i)
end
```

Comment: `hours` available only in ActiveSupport and Rails. Also `end` is a keyword you can't use it.