# Calculate total hours in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

```
Foo.first = {id: 1, start:2000-01-01 07:00:00 UTC, end: 2000-01-01 12:00:00 UTC, total_hours_worked: nil}
```

**`end` is used as an example here.**

I've created `Foo` with `t.time` for both `start` and `end` as I only needed hours/min. I've never worked with Time objects before so bear with me.

I need to get the total hours with minutes with `start` and `end`:

```
start = Foo.find(1).start
end = Foo.find(1).end
start + end #=> errors
start.to_i + end.to_i = 1893438000 #=> What's that?
distance_of_time_in_words(start.to_i + end.to_i) #=> "about 60 years" What?
```

Im expecting `5:00:00`. Im aware that `5:00:00` really means 5am but the context will used different.

Doing few searches I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784527/calculating-difference-in-time-between-two-time-objects). I'm really trying not to use more gems for this "should have baked in method" in Rails/Ruby.

My question will find an answer to what I'm really trying to achieve (get total of hours worked for the week):

```
Foo.pluck(:total_hours_worked).sum(&:to_d) #=> best way?
```

Where `:total_hours_worked` would be a string, just to make things less complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you'd get the format you want (`"5:00:00"`):

```
# Monkeypatch Integer class to add a new method
class Integer
  def pretty_duration
    seconds = self % 60
    minutes = (self / 60) % 60
    hours   = self / (60 * 60)

    format('%02d:%02d:%02d', hours, minutes, seconds)
  end
end

# Get start and end time converted into integers
timestart = (Time.now - 5.hours).to_i
timeend   = Time.now.to_i

# Use pretty_duration method.
# P.S. Difference between time objects already gives you a number, but we need Integer
(timeend - timestart).pretty_duration
#=> "05:00:00"
```

This setup allows you not to be reliant on Rails view helpers (`distance_of_time_in_words`), because you might be in need to have time formatted somewhere beyond the view.

> My question will find an answer to what I'm really trying to achieve
>   (get total of hours worked for the week):
>
> `Foo.pluck(:total_hours_worked).sum(&:to_d)` #=> best way? Where
>   `:total_hours_worked` would be a string, just to make things less
>   complicated.

The most efficient way (if you settle with having `total_hours_worked` as string of correct format) would be summing it up having casted to decimal on the db level:

```
Foo.sum('total_hours_worked::decimal')
```

Comment: you like monkeypatching, eh? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev not so much, it's just that I happen to use this one in my current app :)

Comment: Funny thing about all this, Im eating some monkey nuts as I try this out. haha. I'll confirm.

Answer (score 0):

As you need time between start and end, the code you wrote should be:

```
distance_of_time_in_words(end.to_i - start.to_i)
```

You should be able to format the output using methods described [here](https://hackhands.com/format-datetime-ruby/).

Comment: Spot on! `about 5 hours`. But how to get it as `5:00:00`?

Comment: @Sylar try distance_of_time_in_words((end.to_i - start.to_i) / 1.hour)

Comment: No. I got `less than a minute`

Comment: @Sylar `(end.to_i - start.to_i) / 1.hour` should give you 5.0, you can format using the link I updated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`end` is a keyword. You cannot assign values to it.

Now, getting time difference:

```
start = "2000-01-01 07:00:00 UTC".to_time
endtime = "2000-01-01 12:00:00 UTC".to_time
difference = ((endtime - start) / 1.hour)
# => 5.0
```

or using helper

```
distance_of_time_in_words(endtime, start)
# => "about 5 hours"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to get difference and get the hours in the format as "5:00:00"

```
distance_of_time_in_words(end.to_i - start.to_i).strftime("%H%M%S")

t.strftime("%H:%M:%S") > "22:49:27"
```