# Ruby, difference between time an array was created and the current time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am trying to get the difference between the hours in the time an array was created and the current time, i cant seem to get my head around it, I did this, which seems perfectly logical, but it doesnt seem to ever work.

```
mergelisting = MergeList.Pluck(:created_at, :partner, :gambler, :amount)
  (mergelisting).each do |i|
    t = Time.now
    nowtime = t.strftime("%I")
    nowtime.to_i
    mergetime = i[1].strftime("%I")
    mergetime.to_i
    if nowtime - mergetime == 6
      do some stuff...
    end
  end
```

My real question is the difference in hours between 24 and 6 is 6 hours, but 24-6 would not give 6. What can i do here

Comment: This seems massively complicated. Since you are using Rails, I suggest looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784527/calculating-difference-in-time-between-two-time-objects and http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/between%3F.

Comment: When the difference between mergetime and nowtime is 6hours, do something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `MergeList.Pluck` returns an `Array`, and the first item in this array will be a Rails `created_at` column from the database. Then:

```
mergelisting = MergeList.Pluck(:created_at, :partner, :gambler, :amount)

mergetime  = mergelisting.first           # Time from DB (created_at)
nowtime    = Time.now                     # Current time
timediff_s = nowtime - mergetime          # Difference in seconds
timediff_h = timediff_s / (60 * 60).to_f  # Difference in hours as a floating point number

#
# Not exactly sure if this is what you wanted, but you now
# have the time difference as a floating point number expressed
# in hours. So you can do whatever you want with it
#
if (timediff_h.to_i == 6)
  ...the difference is anywhere between 6.0 and 7.0 hours...
  ...do whatever you need to do...
end
```