# Number of hours between two dates - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I want the difference between tomorrow and now (in hours).

What I've tried:

```
t = (DateTime.tomorrow - DateTime.now)
(t / 3600).to_i
=> 0
```

Why does it give 0?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the values of DateTime.tomorrow and DateTime.now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails Time difference in hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736253/rails-time-difference-in-hours)

Comment: What is the difference betwenn today and tomorrow? 0, because there are no hours betwenn today and tomorrow? 24 hours, because they are different days and a day has 24 hours?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is because `DateTime.tomorrow` does not have any time value. Here:

```
DateTime.tomorrow
# => Wed, 22 Apr 2015
```

If you go through [official document for DateTime](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html) you can see there is no method `tomorrow`. Its basically [`Date#tomorrow`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-c-tomorrow).

You can use `.to_time` to get default localtime `00:00:00`

```
DateTime.tomorrow.to_time
# => 2015-04-22 00:00:00 +0530

(DateTime.tomorrow.to_time - DateTime.now) / 1.hours
# => 9.008116581638655
```

To get exact hour difference between dates:

```
(DateTime.tomorrow.to_time - Date.today.to_time) / 1.hours 
# => 24.0
```

Comment: you could also use (1.day.from_now - DateTime.now) / 3600

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
t = (DateTime.tomorrow.to_time - Date.today.to_time)
t = (t / 3600).to_i
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns rational number. You can take days number if you'll use `round` method:

```
>> (DateTime.tomorrow - DateTime.now).round
1
```

Or if you want to take value in hours from now, use `Time` class:

```
>> (Date.tomorrow.to_time - Time.now) / 1.hour
11.119436663611111
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have two dates like

```
start_time = Time.new(2015,1, 22, 35, 0)
end_time = Time.new(2015,2, 22, 55, 0)
```

Try Time Difference gem for Ruby at https://rubygems.org/gems/time_difference

```
def timediff(start, end)
  TimeDifference.between(start, end).in_hours
end
```

and call it like:

```
timediff(start_time, end_time)
```

It will work.
Cheers!

Comment: You really don't need a gem for such a simple task, if it can be written in one line of code then your simply adding bloat to your app IMO.

Comment: I agree with you @David Battersby. I just meant by this answer this is also a way to handle.

Answer (score 1):

There's [`DateTime#seconds_until_end_of_day`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-seconds_until_end_of_day):

```
seconds = DateTime.now.seconds_until_end_of_day
#=> 41133

seconds / 3600
#=> 11

distance_of_time_in_words(seconds)
=> "about 11 hours"
```