# Rails count hours between two dates for all rows in mysql table

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have this table:

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>first_date</th>
    <th>second_date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2013-12-09 13:00:00</td>
    <td>2013-12-09 14:00:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2013-12-09 13:00:00</td>
    <td>2013-12-10 13:00:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>2013-12-10 15:00:00</td>
    <td>2013-12-10 16:00:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Can a mysql query return the sum of the difference between first_date and second_date in hours for all rows? So 26 hours for my example? The second_date will always be larger than the first_date.

UPDATE:
I have now three approaches and have to choose from:

```
#1. My own approach of looping through each record:

  records = Records.all
  records.each do |r|
    sum += (r.second_date-r.first_date)/1.hour
  end

#2. Using inject(thanks to slowjack2k)

   records = Records.all
   #date_diff is a model method whick substracts the two dates and returns the result
   sum = records.inject(1) {|sum, r| sum + r.date_diff }

#3. the SQL method(thanks to Shadow and slowjack2k)

   sum = Records.sum('time_to_sec(timediff(second_date, first_date))')/1.hour
```

Performance wise they don't seem to differ much. I think I'm going with the SQL method.

Comment: Is this awnser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736253/rails-time-difference-in-hours good enough, or do you need a SQL approach?

Comment: I already have implemented an approach similar to that. The issue with it is that I have to loop through each row in rails to add the difference between the two dates for that row to the total. It's not a huge issue, but I rather do it in SQL if possible.

Comment: Give yout current SQL

Comment: @Michael: The current SQL just pulls all rows from table and loops though them. So:  http://pastebin.com/nxaYeVCx

Comment: An extra loop? Why? It's simply a method within your model. `def date_diff; ((second_date - first_date) / 1.hour).round; end`.  If you need it for multible records `redords.inject(0){|sum, r| sum + r.date_diff }`

Comment: @Shadow: Your link applies to getting the difference between two dates for one row. I need the sum of the difference for all the rows.

Comment: Then just sum the differences calculated on a row basis up in an sql query.

Comment: @slowjack2k: Your solution works and looks better than mine. However, isn' t .inject still looping through all records under the hood?

Comment: Yes, inject does loop under the hood, but for a low amount of records it does not need a lot time more than a round trip to the db to calculate the timediff. It's easy to test and database independent. In other case you need `YourModel.sum('DATEDIFF(second_data, first_date)/3600')`