# Difference in hours between 2 DateTime

Tags: ruby, datetime, timezone

I want to find the difference **in hours** between 2 DateTime. **In Ruby.** What's the best way to do it?

```
a1 = DateTime.now - dt1
=> (84390054590833/28800000000000)

a1.to_i
=> 2 # it's not in hours; the real amount of hours is around 70 for this case
```

Or is it better to convert them both to Time and then subtract? The timezone information must be retained for my task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Time difference in hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736253/rails-time-difference-in-hours)

Comment: @SamHecquet, it's not Rails!

Comment: @SamHecquet Also that question is specifically about Time. DateTime is a different beast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, from the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#class-DateTime-label-When+should+you+use+DateTime+and+when+should+you+use+Time-3F):

> So when should you use `DateTime` in Ruby and when should you use `Time`? Almost certainly you’ll want to use `Time` since your app is probably dealing with current dates and times. However, if you need to deal with dates and times in a historical context you’ll want to use `DateTime`...

If you want to continue using `DateTime`, its subtraction method gives you the difference in *fractions of a day*

```
DateTime.new(2000, 1, 3) - DateTime.new(2000, 1, 1)
# (2/1)
```

Getting that into hours is actually kind of impossible because there aren't always 24 hours per day. You need to convert to `Time` objects to get the difference in seconds, then convert from seconds to hours

```
diff_in_hours = (dt1.to_time - dt2.to_time) / 3_600
```

Comment: what's `in a historical context`?

Comment: Read the documentation I linked to. `DateTime` takes into account how time-keeping methods have changed over the centuries e.g. accurately calculating how long it has been since Shakespeare died. Not a requirement of most applications.

Comment: ok. then how can I find a difference in hours between 2 Time?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736253/time-difference-in-hours

Comment: 24 hours per day is not necessarily a reasonable assumption.  Consider we just had the end of daylight saving time in the US on Sunday.  There were 25 hours in that day. ;)

Comment: @MattJohnson I've had this smoldering in the back my mind all day, and decided it makes much more sense to convert from seconds to hours than days to hours